# Managing Memory in Map-based iOS application

Tags: ios, google-maps, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm developing an enterprise map-based application and it needs to display info gathered from a large workforce and display it all on each worker's iPad. So the number of markers on the map can grow very very large (several thousands) quickly. In addition, each marker is going to be backed by an NSManagedObject subclass that's held in memory while the marker exists.

I'm using Google Maps iOS SDK, and the problem is, even without any markers, just panning and zooming around causes really large increases in memory usage. The application's dirty memory size is 100MB (using Allocations tool) upon launch. Little bit of panning and zooming quickly makes it shoot to up to 300, and the issue is when I stop panning and zooming, the memory never goes down. Similarly if I have a lot of markers on and I remove them, again, no drop in memory (when I remove markers, I make sure to not hold any references to any of the objects too). The only time memory goes down is when I change map types. If I pan/zoom a lot in street view, then switch to satellite view, there's a sudden 50MB+ drop in dirty memory.

So I was wondering if anyone has any tips in handling memory when using Google Maps, or any info on how Google Maps manages/releases memory?